# Exclude results from MySQL based on Content

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently searching my database with the following query. What I really need to do is get 30 results that do not include the tag `#DONE#` that is contained in the information column. The structure of the database is below:

```
ID                  Info1       Info2   Info3           DateAdded
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1235                0000        6       #DONE#infohere  35:27.9
5678                1111        5       #DONE#infohere  47:15.4
4583                2222        7       otherinfohere   47:36.8
1238                3333        9       otherinfohere   47:12.6
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Info3` <> '' LIMIT 0,30
```

So in the full database there is more than 30 of both `Info3` columns that have the `#DONE#` tag and do not have the `#DONE#` tag. What I need to be able to do it to exclude all the results that have the `#DONE#` tag. I do not want to just get all results as that would be extensive on the database when it gets larger but I do need 30 results in the end. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it too late to change the database design? The easiest way would be to add a new column, called DONE, and set it with appropriate values. Otherwise, you're going to have to use a `LIKE` operator instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want NOT LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Info3` NOT LIKE '#DONE#%' LIMIT 0,30
```

EDIT: if #DONE# is not always at the beginning, use %#DONE#%

```
SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Info3` NOT LIKE '%#DONE#%' LIMIT 0,30
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Info3` not like '#DONE#%' LIMIT 0,30
```